# Selenium Python scraping with bs4 is freezing in middle of pagination

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Scraping a website contains 67 pages and need to do pagination but the chrome driver is freezing after page 7.

Code is as follows:

```
while url:
        driver.get(url)
        try:       
            products = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.prodName')
            prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.price[id*=retailpricediv]')
            n = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="prodNotes"]')
            pnumber = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@property="mpn"]')
            print('loading the page')
            time.sleep(15)
            print('loading the products and prices')
            productList = []
            priceList = []
            partnumberList = []
            notesList = []
            for product, price in zip(products,prices):
                productList.append(product.text)
                price = price.text.split('/n')[0].replace('Price: ','')
                priceList.append(price.replace("\nSAVE NOW - See Details",""))

            for note in n:
                notes = note.text
                notesList.append(notes.replace('Notes: ',''))

            for part in pnumber:
                partnumberList.append(part.text)



                    # df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':productList,'Price':priceList})
                    # print(df)
            total = []
            for product, price, partnumber, notes in zip(productList, priceList, partnumberList, notesList):
                data = { 'name': product, 'price': price, 'partnumber' : partnumber, 'notes' : notes }
                total.append(data)


            link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='pageNext']/a")
            url = link.get_attribute("href")
```

Why is it happening ? Please help.

Comment: Can you update any error trace if there's any? Also, update the `url` of the site so that we can look into what's going wrong.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 site url is https://www.autozone.com/ i need to scrap all the sub-categories and products of the site and there is no error selenium just stopped working